# MYSQL Like Improper results

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like

I am using Like to find something pattern from table

sample table:

```
id | title |
=============
 1 | f550  |
-------------
 2 | f550  |
-------------
 3 | f-550 |
-------------
 4 | f 550 |
```

I am using LIke query to check my receords, so lets say if I search for f550 it is bringing only 2 records that is correct technically but I want all records having any pattern such as (f550,f-550,f 550)

Is there any way besides REGEX I can do?

My query fires like this

```
SELECT * FROM `qd_posts` WHERE title LIKE  '%f550%';
```

I tried using different combinations such like this but didn't worked.

```
SELECT * FROM `qd_posts` WHERE title LIKE  '%f%-%550%';
```

I have even tried using RLIKE but still not got the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using  `'%f%550%'`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `qd_posts` 
WHERE title LIKE  '%f%550%';
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM `qd_posts` 
WHERE title LIKE  'f%' AND LIKE '%550';
```

Comment: No idea that worked, had an assumption that wildcards only worked in front or trailing. Cool. No regex!

Comment: Yes that gives me better results but imagine user typing from tetxbox anything can be entered shall I explicitly make different conditions?

Comment: @BitsPlease  .  i can just answer  at the question you posted ..  . anyway  ,.. for user inputs also for regex there are possible limits ..  .. for user  input could be you need  some validation rule

Comment: The first one will match "TGIF at 1550"; did you want that?  The second one can be simplified to just `LIKE 'f%550'.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific list given `(f550,f-550,f 550)`, use this:

```
REGEXP '^f[- ]?550$'
```

Yes, `LIKE 'f%550'` matches the same things, but lots more.